# Installed package number rarely equals removed package number

Tags: centos, fedora, package-management, yum, dnf

I am running CentOS 8. Often when I install a package with a lot of dependencies and then remove the package, the number of removed packages is rarely the same as the amount I installed originally.

At first I thought they were being orphaned but this is not the case, as running `package-cleanup` or `dnf-autoremove` yields nothing.

Where are these packages going? Why didn't I have them before if they were being used by some other package?

See for example

```
[root@localhost user]# yum history
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   102 | remove steam             | 2020-04-20 20:21 | Removed        |   12   
   101 | install steam            | 2020-04-20 18:52 | Install        |  146
```

Comment: Is `clean_requirements_on_remove` enabled in dnf.conf? When you do `dnf history info 101` and `dnf history info 102`, exactly which packages are getting uninstalled and which ones aren't?